# How to calculate $\int udF(u)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

According to a geostatistics book,

\begin{array}{}
Q(z) &= \int_{z}^{\infty} u dF(u)\\
& = \bigg[-uT(u)\bigg]_{z}^{\infty} + \int_{z}^{\infty} T(u)du
\end{array}

where $F(u)$ is a cumulative distribution and $T(u)$ is $1-F(u)$, which I think is called the complementary cumulative distribution.

However, I can't reproduce this result.

I tried the following:

\begin{array}{}
\int_{z}^{\infty} u dF(u) = \int_{z}^{\infty} u d(1-T(u)) = -\int_{z}^{\infty} u dT(u)
\end{array}

Then integrating by parts, I get:

$$-\left(-uT(u)\bigg|_{z}^{\infty}+ \int_{z}^{\infty}T(u)du\right)$$

Notice that the signs are reversed compared to the correct result.

Maybe I'm making a mistake in the integration by parts because I assigned $dv/du = dT(u)$ and integrating I would get $v = T(\infty) - T(u) = -T(u)$, which seems suspicious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot your minus sign.

Noting that

$$-\int_z^\infty u dT(u) = 
- u T(u) \Biggr|_z^\infty + \int_z^\infty T(u) du,
$$

you get the correct result.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the result I wrote wasn't considering the minus sign outside of the integral. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Where are you getting the extra minus sign?

Comment: I see now.  No, define $dv/du=dT(u)$. Then $v=T(u)$.  Yes, it really is that simple.

Comment: It could be from integrating by parts in which $v = -T(u)$. I don't think the first equation with the complementary cumulative distribution is wrong.

Comment: That's right: if $v=T(u)$ then $dv/du=dT(u)$.

Comment: Oh... right! I don't know why I wanted to evaluate the integral there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are integrating by parts the wrong way.
The rule is:
$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$
Therefore:
$$-\int udT(u) = -\left(uT(u) - \int T(u)du\right)$$

Comment: Yes. For some reason, I felt compelled to evaluate the integral there :-/